# What is a decent open-source list/task management software

Tags: webapp-rec, open-source, tasks

I really like the application [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/) but I need something web-based. Ideally something I can host on my server. So simply, PHP/MySQl based task-management software, which is open-source.

What would be ideal would be something where I can drag and drop to reorder the tasks.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about [Tasks Jr.](http://crowdfavorite.com/tasks-jr/)?

Answer (score 1):

A rails offering: [Tracks](http://www.getontracks.org/). Host it on your own server (or PC). I've used it in the past and liked it.

> Tracks is a web-based application to
>   help you implement David Allen’s
>   Getting Things Done™ methodology. It
>   was built using Ruby on Rails, and
>   comes with a built-in webserver
>   (WEBrick), so that you can run it on
>   your own computer if you like. It can
>   be run on any platform on which Ruby
>   can be installed, including Mac OS X,
>   Windows XP and Linux. Tracks is Open
>   Source, free and licensed under the
>   GNU GPL.

Answer (score 1):

[Wunderlist](http://www.wunderlist.com/) is somehow similar to Things, but it offers a web version as well. Not open source or self-hosted thou.

Answer (score 0):

I use Tasks Pro, because it has a good interface, but unfortunately it does not provide a drag and drop feature.

To drag and drop tasks (and a nice clean interface), I recommend [Todoist](http://todoist.com/), which unfortunately is **not** open source, and **not** self-hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ones, which you can also install on your own server - open source - using php and mysql.

http://www.plancake.com/ (support GDT)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Google Tasks](http://mail.google.com/tasks/). That is such a nice tool to manage your daily tasks.

Log in to your Gmail account and you'll see a link to **Tasks** under **Mail** and **Contacts** links, on the left side.

[image]

Comment: but I am sorry, it is not `open-source`. you can not host it on your own server.

Answer (score 0):

We've been happily using [NetOffice](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netoffice/) for several years now and although it's intended for working on projects as a group, when compared to the *Things* feature list it can do most of those things and then some, with exception to iCal/iPhone sync.

Answer (score 0):

Not something you can put on your own server, nor even open source, but [Trello](http://www.trello.com) is very good for this kind of thing.